# This is not a farewell…

Tags: discussion

### This is not a farewell, but rather an explanation.

#### What happened?

As some of you might have noticed, I have not been hanging out on SuperUser — or any Stack Exchange site — nowadays as much as I had been in the past.

The reason is simple: On April 5, 2023 I suffered a stoke. Left capsule in the language center for anyone who knows about such things.

I am fine now, and am recovering well but for a period of time after the stoke I could barely type. I am a righty and I could not even accurately hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> to save my life. In fact, I almost locked myself out of my iPhone when typing the passcode.

I even had to type out and copy-and-paste passwords if at least to see them!

#### How it’s going?

Now, nearly 2-3 months later I can type better and generally lead a normal life. But one thing has significantly changed: I am nowhere near as impulsive for even OCD as I used to be.

That said, I don’t really have the urge to login and post here. It just doesn’t feel like a thing anymore.

I type and code for work, do my work and then in my free time I don't have the urge to do this stuff.

That’s it! I have no ill will towards SuperUser and Stack Exchange; it has helped me many times it the past and even currently with issues.

But as far as actively coming back? I don’t know. The road to recovery is a  long one and I cannot predict what the future might hold. But for now I don’t think active participation is a thing that I will be coming back to.

So farewell SuperUser! I will still be voting, and making small edits here and there, but that’s about it.

Comment: I wish you well for a steady and good recovery.

Comment: All the best mate, your health comes above everything.

Comment: That sucks. Good luck with your recovery, I know this is going to be a rough road.

Comment: As Hashim said above - your health matters more than anything else. I hope you find something in your spare time that will give you the satisfaction SuperUser did. Good luck, and I hope things get better for you.

Comment: Thanks for all your contributions. It’s natural for many people to drop off (I’ve seen/heard the same from many prolific [su] contributors) so don’t worry about it. Take care of your health.

Comment: Take it easy and focus on rest and recovery.